# After using vue3-notification in laravel sail and vite, I got "permission denied" on non-existing directory, what can I do?

Tags: laravel, docker, vuejs3, laravel-sail, laravel-vite

I'm trying to add this package
https://github.com/kyvg/vue3-notification

I'm using vue3 with laravel sail and vite, after installing this package, my "sail npm run dev" command prints an error

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/var/www/html/node_modules/.vite/deps/@inertiajs_inertia-vue3.js'
    at unlinkSync (node:fs:1780:3)
    at _unlinkSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:214:14)
    ...
```

I  tried to chmod that directory, but I don't even have directory "www" inside my "var" directory, so there is nothing to change.
What can I do to make it work?

My versions:

```
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.41"
        "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node_modules` directory and install it again with `sail npm i`.